# RoR Storing Data w/Forms Without Writing to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, sqlite

I am really having trouble accomplishing a simple task in RoR.  Instead of writing to the DB from a form, I just want the user to fill in the form and click "Next" without writing this to the DB, on the next page I will have the user click "Submit" where it would write to the DB.

Can someone help me understand the HTTP verbs GET, POST, etc. and how to integrate that into my Controller?  I'm not sure if I need to alter the code in the `form_for` tags either.

I have something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@trek) do |t| %>
.
.
<%= t.submit "Create Trek" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks guys...All help is appreciated for this guy trying to learn RoR :/

EDIT...below is the controller actions for 'create', 'new', and 'review'.  I wanted the 'review' action to be the place where they can review then submit the data.

```
def new
  @trek = Trek.new
  @title = "Share Adventures with Friends"
end

def create
  @trek = Trek.new(params[:trek])
  if @trek.save
    flash[:success] = "Congrats!"
  render 'review'
else
  @title = "Share Adventures with Friends"
  render 'new'
end
end

def review
  @trek = Trek.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: This would all be handled by the controller, so posting the relevant controller code would be more helpful than the view

Comment: @Jamie Wong - thanks...added the controller code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `review`, you're trying to pull something from that database which you specifically do not want to be in the database (and since you haven't yet saved it, it isn't in the database). What you probably want instead is this:

```
def review
  @trek = Trek.new(params[:trek])
end
```

You'll also need to modify the `form_for` there assuming you want that form to submit to `review` instead of to `create`.

Which you do do like this:

```
<%= form_for @trek, :url => { :action => :review } do |t| %>
.
.
<%= t.submit "Create Trek" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```